# D3 zoom large images performance has huge lag

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, svg, memory-leaks

I am using d3.geo and d3.zoom to create a 2d map. It works pretty nice but when I add a big resolution image (5120x2880) to map SVG then I am getting weird performance lag. I can't understand why it happens.

```
Code: https://plnkr.co/edit/frhUsAwC6cBU3V5q
```

Steps I am doing:

1. Create an SVG of a world map using geojson with d3.geo.
2. Add 10 images to SVG which by default all display:none except the first one. The bounding box of the images is on the USA.
3. Then enabled zoom on this whole SVG so images get zoomed with a map.
4. Have a slider on top with range 0-9. Depending on the value slider is on
   I show the corresponding image and hide all others.

Now sliding slider back and forth it switches images rendered. It is pretty smooth. But as I keep zooming in soon slider has a huge lag. Although the only thing I do with slider is just showing and hide the image.

Plunker I created for this: https://plnkr.co/edit/frhUsAwC6cBU3V5q

Looks like a memory leak or something.

Looks like:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you roll the slider to all the images first, when you get back to them, the lag doesn't happen.

The issue is that you don't `preload` the images. You load them only when the user selects on the slider, so the browser has to download and render the image on the fly, and it may take a while depending on your internet connection.

Comment: Yeah but this lag does not happen when not zoomed in. When you zoom in then try to slide. It will have lag no matter if images are already shown at least once.

Comment: So if you slide all the way to make sure that each image is loaded at least once and slider becomes smooth. Now zoom in to some extent deep enough. You will see slider again has a lag and not no matter how much you zoom out it will keep having a lag.

Comment: Her is an example that has pre-loaded images in memory https://plnkr.co/edit/5Gm7frsoEi8dLtkG?preview same issue here

Comment: Alright, I can't see any issue on my machine, it doesn't flicker to me. The only issue that I saw happening was the image loading on the fly, but I can't take it as a parameter if the image loading is not the issue, probably the issue is not with `d3` itself, but with the image size, if it's too big, then your computer may struggle to render/rerender it, I can't reproduce it here.